# How to create a DATA partition accessible by multiple users and multiple linux OS?

Tags: mount, filesystem, ntfs, partitioning, ext4

In my disk I have many linux Operating Systems installed with many different users each (with different uid). I want to create a DATA partition which will have music, videos and movies, torrents, dropbox etc... and some other content which I need to share between multiple users (like steamapps, thunderbird, goldendict dictionaries, etc...). I want all the above to be accessible by multiple users and multiple linux Operating Systems, including live images.

Right now I have created an ext4 partition but I have problems with multiple users, because every time that I change something from the 1 user, then I need to change the permissions again, which makes the whole purpose fail.

Is there any way to avoid the permissions nightmare and keep all the files accessible by everyone all the time? I am thinking of using **ntfs** filesystem for the DATA partition which can be given permission rights during mount, but I would really like to use some "native" linux filesystem (since I don't use Windows or anything else anymore). Is there any way?

Answer (score 4):

> Right now I have created an ext4 partition but I have problems with multiple users, because every time that I change something from the 1 user, then I need to change the permissions again, which makes the whole purpose fail.

I got 1 word for you: groups

- permissions can be set for one user; example /home/$USER/
- permissions can be set for a group of users; that would/could be a datadirectory.

So ...

- Create a group "allusers": `sudo groupadd allusers`
- Add user rinzwind to that group: `sudo usermod -a -G allusers rinzwind`
- Create a partition, give it a mountpoint (let's call it "discworld");
- Change the group of the mountpoint to a group;

  ```
  chgrp-R allusers /discworld/
  ```
- A user added after this you will need to add to the group for that user to gain access.

For new files to get the group set on creation:

- Use `grpid` on the mount.
- or use `sudo setfacl -Rdm g:allusers:rx /discworld/` to use the ACL method (`getfacl /discword` to list permissions).

---

If you want a really fancy setup:

```
/discworld/user1/
/discworld/user2/
/discworld/user3/
/discworld/user4/
/discworld/user5/
/discworld/common/
```

- set these to owner user{1-5} and group user{1-5} and users can use this as private data.
- set common to group "allusers" and add user{1-5} to group "allusers".
- you can use a "filesystem quota" on the user or on the group to limit the amount of data.

---

---

> I am thinking of using ntfs filesystem for the DATA partition which can be given permission rights during mount,

Only use NTFS when you also have a Windows; otherwise you can get in trouble when it does not mount due to errors. It might be fixable, it might not. Just don't take the risk.

- Basically the same method: mount the partition with group "allusers". You can add a `gid=allusers,umask=0022` to the mount options.

Comment: Nice answer, explains a lot. I just have one problem. After I add users to the group then they can read and write files. But if I create a new file there then it has the user's group by default (for example in Antergos newly created belong to the group "users"). How can I make newly created files at this mount point to belong to group "allusers" in all my systems and for all applications (like torrent downloads) by default?

Comment: Possible methods: `grpid` on the mount or `sudo setfacl -Rdm g:allusers:rx /discworld/` (both are 1 time actions) (`getfacl /discword` will show the permissions)

Comment: Yeah the `grpid` in fstab did the trick. Please add it to the answer in order to be complete. One last question. Is the group name matter or is it the group id? For example if group "allusers" in Antergos takes id 1002, but in Ubuntu it takes id 1005 (because maybe other groups have already taken the id) will it be a problem? Should I better use `sudo groupadd allusers -g 1111` in all systems so that the group has the exact same unique id?

Comment: The group id matters. But for human readability the name too.

Comment: Ok nice, if you can add it as a note or something where you mention the groupadd command, in case that someone doesn't know about it.  Thx for the complete answer!

Comment: This doesn't work properly after all. Newly created files belong to allusers group, however when I copy files (that applies also to every application which uses cp), then the creator's group is preserved making the files not editable by others (https://serverfault.com/questions/183800/why-does-cp-not-respect-acls?newreg=12aa9b4cfced42febdf112e64dbe3a8b). So any other solution or shall I change it to ntfs after all?